Accounting for varying estimate precision when comparing proportions
I am stuck on an apparently simple problem that has been perplexing me for several days, without finding a solution.
Here is the question:
I have seroprevalence estimates (i.e., the prevalence of antibody-positive individuals) from several epidemiological units (cattle herds), with half of the herds having characteristic A = yes, and the other half having characteristic A = no. The precision of these estimates varies across herds because the within-herd sampling rates differ (ranging from 0.2 to 1). How can I account for this variation in precision when assessing whether characteristic A is associated with within-herd seroprevalence?
Please note that the herds vary in size and are finite, meaning that 30 sampled and tested individuals could represent anywhere from 20% to 100% of the entire herd.
Would inverse variance weighting be appropriate? If so, how should I handle units that were completely sampled (where variance = 0)?
Thank you in advance for any kind of advices.
